# Python Regular Expression Problem with Numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to find the space after 3 or 4 digits in a bunch of filenames and replace the space with an underscore.  But I can't seem to even find 4 digits together.

```
s = "the blue dog and blue cat wore blue hats"
p = re.compile(r'blue (?P<animal>dog|cat)')
print(p.sub(r'gray \g<animal>',s))

#Gives basically what I want.
the gray dog and gray cat wore blue hats


s = "7053 MyFile.pptx"
p = re.compile('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9](?P<dig> )')
print(p.sub('_\g<dig>', s))

#Takes out the numbers, which I need to keep
_ MyFile.pptx
```

Everything I seem to do has the expression taking out the digits, which I need to keep.

In the end, I want

7035 MyFile.pptx

to be

7035_MyFile.pptx

Comment: Why overcomplicate a simple task by using regex? You can just split on the whitespace and join the resulting list on `"_"`.

Comment: There are other file names with white space in it.

1234 Some Other File.pptx


Plus I need to get better with my regex :)

Comment: That's still no issue as long as the filenames start with the digits. But sure you can a use regex for this task; I'm just recommending not to if this goes beyond personal projects/exploration.

Comment: Why not just use ```s.replace(' ', '_')```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I you want to replace 3 or 4 digits followed by a white space with the same digit followed by an underscore, the correct regex syntax/substitution would be:

```
re.sub(r"([0-9]{3,4})\s", r"\1_", s)
```

You might have misread how the groups/back references work. What is supposed to be in the group, needs to be inside the parenthesis. If you wanted to use a named group (which is a bit unnecessary):

```
re.sub(r"(?P<dig>[0-9]{3,4})\s", r"\g<dig>_", s)
```

Or with a pre-compiled regex akin to your example:

```
s = "7053 MyFile.pptx"
p = re.compile(r"(?P<dig>[0-9]{3,4})\s")
print(p.sub('\g<dig>_', s))
```

`{3,4}` following `[0-9]` means three or four matches. `\s` stands for a white space (not just a space).

Actually just looking for 3 digits as written would also match 4 digits, because we do not limit what happens before the matching pattern. Depending on what you are looking for, you may want to limit the matches by prepending the pattern with `^` (beginning of line) or `\b` empty character at word edge...